# how do I inject an object from my html into the jsRender template

Tags: razor, jsrender

In my cshtml I start off with some regular html/razor syntax
which go in the form

```
@foreach (var product in Model.Basket.Items
{
 ……
  <div class="itemMessageContent></div>
}
```

where the div is the target of my template.

So how do I inject product into the template? or is it already available to me on the basis the div's in side my foreach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recommend add the template before the `</body>` tag:

```
<script id="template" type="text/x-jsrender">
    {{:name}}
</script>
```

### Data attribute way

Most obvious and somewhat erroneous decision.

Add to your project **[Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm)**

```
Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
```

Update code:

```
@foreach (var product in Model.Basket.Items)
{
  <div data-jsrender='@JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product)' class="itemMessageContent"></div>
}
```

The following html should turn out:

```
 <div data-jsrender='{name="Apple"}' class="itemMessageContent></div>
 <div data-jsrender='{name="Banana"}' class="itemMessageContent></div>
```

Now you can render data:

```
var template = $('#template');
$('.itemMessageContent').each(function(){
    var element = $(this);
    var data = element.data('jsrender');
    element.html(template.render(data));
})
```